# How to base64 encode a string (request_uri) during rewrite?

Tags: nginx

In the following code, I would like to base-64 encode $request_uri to prevent any unwanted character to interfere with the redirect process (for example `?`, `space`, etc.)

```
server {
   listen 443 default_server;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/nginx/certificate.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx/key.key;

   rewrite ^ $request_uri;   
   return 302 https://my.domain.com/?req=$host$request_uri;
}
```

(yes I redirect any requested domain on purpose).

I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: There are no built-in functionality to do it. You can use 3rd party modules, e.g. [`set_encode_base64`](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#set_encode_base64) from [set-misc-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module) or [`ngx.encode_base64`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxencode_base64) from [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module). Both are included into the [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/) bundle.

Comment: Thx. I will look into it.

Comment: NJS can do that with the NGINX NJS module. Use `js_var` or `js_set` to create a variable that represents the base64 encoded version of your  `request_uri`